# How to check if a filesystem::path is a file?

Tags: c++, c++17, filepath

I have a function that should write binary data, the path is supplied by the user.

How can I check if a given filepath is a writable file path?
`is_regular_file()` returns false for a given file path:

- `D:/SomePath` should be a writable file (note the missing `/` at the end)
- `D:/SomePath/File.txt` is also a writable file
- `D:/SomePath/File` is a writable file
- `D:/SomePath/SomeSubDir/` is a directory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    string file = "D:/SomeFile.txt";
    string file2 = "D:/SomeFile";
    string directory = "D:/Files/";
    filesystem::path p1 = file;
    filesystem::path p2 = directory;
    filesystem::path p3 = file2;
    cout << "file is_regular_file() : " << (filesystem::is_regular_file(p1) ? "true" : "false") << endl; //should return true
    cout << "directory is_regular_file() : " << (filesystem::is_regular_file(p2) ? "true" : "false") << endl; // should return false
    cout << "file_no_extension is_regular_file() : " << (filesystem::is_regular_file(p3) ? "true" : "false") << endl; // should return true
}
```

all three calls to `is_regular_file()` return false, although i would the first and last expect to be  `true` ...

I am on windows, but that shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: shouldn't that be "D:\\SomeFile.txt" if you're on windows?

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski I believe it understands both.

Comment: Do these paths *exist*? *Are* they files or directories? Whether there’s a trailing slash in the path should be mostly irrelevant: `is_regular_file` checks the actual file type and returns `true` if and only if the file exists *and* is a regular file.

Comment: @KonradRudolph i see, so I misunderstood the API.
Is there a way to check it when the file/directory does not exist yet?

Comment: @Raildex No, there’s no way, since the question simply doesn’t make sense for non-existent paths.

Comment: Just open for write.  If it fails, then you know.

Comment: If your definition of "is path a directory" is "the string representation ends with a trailing slash", then you can just directly check whether the string representation ends with a trailing slash.

Comment: OT but you don't need all those ternaries. Just use `std::boolalpha`.

Comment: Are you looking for `path::has_filename()`?

Comment: @Raildex: "*D:/SomePath should be a writable file*" Should it? If `SomePath` is a directory, then it should not be a "writable file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - `D:/SomePath` should be a writable file (note the missing `/` at the end)
> - `D:/SomePath/File.txt` is also a writable file
> - `D:/SomePath/File` is a writable file
> - `D:/SomePath/SomeSubDir/` is a directory.

I would argue that the term "writable file" does not apply some of these. What you're asking for is if the path has a filename, which `std::filesystem::path` can test with `has_filename`.

Of course, that's just a matter of string testing. It has no way of knowing if that represents an actual *thing* in the filesystem. That requires checking `filesystem::exists`.

Comment: this not work, a path also have has_filename.